# Array group by twice and count occurrences

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting, lodash

I have the following array:

```
var array = [
  { idOne: 1, oneText: 'one', idTwo: 2, twoText: 'two' },
  { idOne: 1, oneText: 'one', idTwo: 2, twoText: 'two' },
  { idOne: 12, oneText: 'twelve', idTwo: 23, twoText: 'twentythree' },
  { idOne: 12, oneText: 'twelve', idTwo: 23, twoText: 'twentythree' },
  { idOne: 12, oneText: 'twelve', idTwo: 25, twoText: 'twentyfive' },
  { idOne: 16, oneText: 'sixteen', idTwo: 56, twoText: 'fiftysix' },
  { idOne: 16, oneText: 'sixteen', idTwo: 56, twoText: 'fiftysix' },
  { idOne: 16, oneText: 'sixteen', idTwo: 56, twoText: 'fiftysix' },
  { idOne: 16, oneText: 'sixteen', idTwo: 50, twoText: 'fifty' },
  { idOne: 16, oneText: 'sixteen', idTwo: 50, twoText: 'fifty' },
  { idOne: 18, oneText: 'eighteen', idTwo: 90, twoText: 'ninety' }
];
```

I'm trying to group them first by idOne, then by idTwo, and count how many of them are found, and then sort them:

I currently have the following method:

```
var result = _.chain(array)
    .groupBy("idOne")
    .map(function(idOne, idOneKey) {
        return _.chain(idOne)
            .groupBy("idTwo")
            .map(function(idTwo, idTwoKey) {
                return {                
                    id: idOneKey + '-' + idTwoKey
                }
            })
            .value();
    })
    .value();
```

But I want to return the following array or object, not sure which one would be best:

```
result = {
  'one-two': 2,
  'twelve-twentythree': 2,
  'twelve-twentyfive': 1,
  'sixteen-fiftysix': 3
  ...
}
```

It does not have to be with underscore or lodash, just whatever it works.

Comment: is native JS solution allowed?

Comment: I'm implementing this in a react app, so whatever works really...

Comment: wouldnt you want an object with a structure like: {[idOne]:{[idTwo]:{object}}}? essentially a map of maps to the objects?

Comment: I have to use this in a chart, so I'll need to do it anyway in the future. 
Each combination of the 2 keys is the label, each length of them is the value

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use [**countBy**](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#countBy) instead of groupBy:

```
let result = _.countBy(array, item => item.oneText + '-' + item.twoText);
```

Answer (score 2):

*Ecamscript5* alternative solution (based on `Array.reduce()` function):

```js
var arr = [
  { idOne: 1, oneText: 'one', idTwo: 2, twoText: 'two' }, { idOne: 1, oneText: 'one', idTwo: 2, twoText: 'two' }, 
  { idOne: 12, oneText: 'twelve', idTwo: 23, twoText: 'twentythree' }, { idOne: 12, oneText: 'twelve', idTwo: 23, twoText: 'twentythree' },
  { idOne: 12, oneText: 'twelve', idTwo: 25, twoText: 'twentyfive' }, { idOne: 16, oneText: 'sixteen', idTwo: 56, twoText: 'fiftysix' },
  { idOne: 16, oneText: 'sixteen', idTwo: 56, twoText: 'fiftysix' }, { idOne: 16, oneText: 'sixteen', idTwo: 56, twoText: 'fiftysix' },
  { idOne: 16, oneText: 'sixteen', idTwo: 50, twoText: 'fifty' }, { idOne: 16, oneText: 'sixteen', idTwo: 50, twoText: 'fifty' },
  { idOne: 18, oneText: 'eighteen', idTwo: 90, twoText: 'ninety' }
],
result = arr.reduce(function(r, o){
    var k = o.oneText +'-'+ o.twoText;
    r[k] = (r[k])? (r[k]+1) : 1;
    return r;
}, {});

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use an array for the keys to group on for the hash table to count.

```js
var array = [{ idOne: 1, oneText: 'one', idTwo: 2, twoText: 'two' }, { idOne: 1, oneText: 'one', idTwo: 2, twoText: 'two' }, { idOne: 12, oneText: 'twelve', idTwo: 23, twoText: 'twentythree' }, { idOne: 12, oneText: 'twelve', idTwo: 23, twoText: 'twentythree' }, { idOne: 12, oneText: 'twelve', idTwo: 25, twoText: 'twentyfive' }, { idOne: 16, oneText: 'sixteen', idTwo: 56, twoText: 'fiftysix' }, { idOne: 16, oneText: 'sixteen', idTwo: 56, twoText: 'fiftysix' }, { idOne: 16, oneText: 'sixteen', idTwo: 56, twoText: 'fiftysix' }, { idOne: 16, oneText: 'sixteen', idTwo: 50, twoText: 'fifty' }, { idOne: 16, oneText: 'sixteen', idTwo: 50, twoText: 'fifty' }, { idOne: 18, oneText: 'eighteen', idTwo: 90, twoText: 'ninety' }],
    result = {};

array.forEach(function (o) {
    var key = ['oneText', 'twoText'].map(k => o[k]).join('-');
    result[key] = (result[key] || 0) + 1;
});

console.log(result);
```